# Delphi, read SQL Server stored procedure with nvarchar(max) output parameter

Tags: sql-server, delphi, stored-procedures, nvarchar

Using Delphi XE7 and SQL Server 2008. I have a stored procedure which looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspUsers_GetAll]
    @ReturnData nvarchar(max) = NULL OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @ReturnData = CONVERT(nvarchar(max),
                    (SELECT *, (SELECT UserID, RightType
                                FROM UserRights
                                WHERE UserRights.UserID = Users.ID
                                FOR XML RAW('UserRight'), 
                                ROOT('UserRights'), ELEMENTS, TYPE)
                     FROM Users
                     FOR XML RAW('Users'), ROOT('root') , ELEMENTS));
END;
```

What I want to do is to return all the users and their rights in an xml converted into a string. The point is that on the client side, will read the string and turn it into an XML document.

I execute the stored procedure using `TADOStoredProc` like this:

```
  uspAdoWork.Close;

  if uspAdoWork.Prepared then
     uspAdoWork.Prepared := False;

  uspAdoWork.Parameters.Clear;
  uspAdoWork.ProcedureName := 'uspUsers_GetAll';
  uspAdoWork.Parameters.Refresh;
  uspAdoWork.Prepared := True;

  dmApp.uspAdoWork.ExecProc;

  RetXML := uspAdoWork.Parameters.ParamByName('@ReturnData').Value;
```

My problem is that the returned value is cut off after 4000 characters. I did read something about this limitation. Is there a way to avoid it (some kind of workaround)?

Comment: Why not avoid the problem in the first place by returning the data from the server either as a series of user rows or as a TEXT column, and do the XML construction entirely in the client?

Comment: If the SQL server is capable to create an XML then isn't it possible to receive that XML using ado?

Comment: Just because a server *can* do something, doesn't mean it's the *best* way to do it, does it?  The problem you are having is a perfect illustration of that.

Comment: Try using SQL Server Native Client instead of SQLOLEDB.1

Comment: @MartynA How would you return from the SQL server a customer with contacts, quotations, customer orders, invoices, etc without a query for each set of data?

Comment: @kobik Did try with SQLNCLI11 provider and I'm getting "Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided."

Comment: I'm not sure whether that is a rhetorical q.  Anyway, the way I have done similar in the past is to use a stored proc that returns multiple result sets, one from each table or view, then retrieved them in the client (actually, in the middle tier of a 3-tier system) using calls to NextRecordSet (see AdoDB.Pas).  It's very simple and extremely quick.

Comment: @MartynA, You might be right about your workaround suggestion, I might also consider multiple record-sets in *this case* but You are ignoring the *question* (which I think is very good and clear). Again I'm 99% sure its a provider issue. I can't test it right now. That said, OP does asking for *some kind of workaround*. What kind? I don't know. I would have investigated this issue.

Comment: @BenjiK, *"Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided"*, 1) Try accessing the value by parameter index, 2) Try creating the parameter yourself providing the type explicitly without using Parameters.Refresh. You have a lot you can try first...

Comment: Using multiple record-sets may be a solution but I have a 2 way communication - built stored procedures with nvarchar(max) in parameter which is an xml processed inside a stored procedure. First I was using FireDac components (TFDStoredProc) and it was working but then I moved the database and the application into another system and I'm getting this error: "[FireDAC][Phys][ODBC][Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error."
So, application working on Windows 8 doesn't work on Windows 7 and XP - maybe you have an idea how to solve this problem!?

Answer (score 1):

Turn it into a column to avoid parameter issues.

Use this in your SQLDataSet.CommandText or Query.SQL:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);

EXECUTE [dbo].[uspUsers_GetAll] @ReturnData=@json OUTPUT;

SELECT @json AS JSON
```

**Using:**

```
var
  jsonStr: string;
begin
  sqlDataSet1.Open;
  jsonStr := sqlDataSet1.FieldByName('JSON').AsString;
```

...